# Window shown as dialogue losts its focus - wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a main window Say **home** and from there i am calling another window named **addItem**  as

```
var item = new addItem();
item.ShowDialog();
```

Its working fine.
But when we navigate to other applications like chrome, notepad by alt + tab and come back to the WPF application both the windows are separated meaning as like in winforms it wont stick together

So user got confused in that behavior.

**Requirement**  is unless until the dialogue window is opened it should always 
be on top and main window on the back and when we click the icon in task bar both window together should come.

Comment: Where do you call that code from?

Comment: from the main window

Comment: Try to set the `Owner` property of the new window to the main window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 var item = new addItem();
 item.Owner = this;
 item.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks man this works fine. But If i am navigating from a usercontrol to a window then how to set this ?